Залив тг бота на сервер
Всех приветствую, выкладываю бота на amvera, но к сожалению выскакивает такая ошибка:
python3: can't open file 'tg2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "tg2.py", line 2, in <module>

File "/app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>

from .dispatcher.dispatcher import Dispatcher

File "/app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 11, in <module>

from .. import loggers

ImportError: cannot import name 'loggers' from partially initialized module 'aiogram' (most likely due to a circular import) (/app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/__init__.py)

python3: can't open file 'tg2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Сам код(полностью скидывать не буду, так как ошибка идет именно на этот файл):
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher

from models import async_main

from handlers import router


import config

async def main():
    await async_main()
    bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.include_router(router)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Бот выключен')

библиотеки models и handlers это другие скрипты.
Ошибка не возникает когда включаю ее на компьютере(mac os).
Только на сервере.
Буду рад, если ответите как исправить эту ошибку.
Также прикладываю файл requirements.txt:
aiogram==3.6.0
aiosqlite==0.20.0
asyncio==3.4.3
SQLAlchemy==2.0.31

